# How to check if uploaded file is binary file?

Tags: php

How to check if the uploaded file is binary file in PHP?
and How to check if string is binary?

Answer (score 1):

```
function IsBinary($file) 
{ 
  if (file_exists($file)) { 
    if (!is_file($file)) return 0; 

    $fh  = fopen($file, "r"); 
    $blk = fread($fh, 512); 
    fclose($fh); 
    clearstatcache(); 

    return ( 
      0 or substr_count($blk, "^ -~", "^\r\n")/512 > 0.3 
        or substr_count($blk, "\x00") > 0 
    ); 
  } 
  return 0; 
}
```

Comment: http://www.ultrashock.com/forums/server-side/checking-if-a-file-is-binary-98391.html

Comment: This is for files only. How to check string?

Answer (score 0):

What you mean binary? You can traverse this file and if you get some nonprintable characters you can recognize this like binary.